# Rep Awarded for Referrals from a Different Question

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, hyperlinks

Hi All I am rather new here, wondering about this

```
Scenario:
```

Jim asks Q1.

Kyle posts accepted answer A1.

Mary posts answer B1 that was not accepted.

later...

A new question Q2 is asked, seemingly unrelated to (at least, not marked as a duplicate of) Q1. Nancy notices Q2 would be well-answered by pointing to answer B1 instead of repeating B1 outright. Perhaps B1 was more extensible/more generalized/more useful.

My question: Does (or should) Mary get reputation for her answer by way of referral? How about Nancy?

Comment: Posting links to other questions or answers on the network *as* an answer is discouraged. If Nancy posts a link to Mary's answer in the comments, then yes Mary can get upvotes. There's nothing stopping Mary from gaining more reputation, but Nancy should not be gaining reputation from work she didn't actually do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure - *if* Nancy actually answers the question linking to B1 as a resource.

This is really no different from answering a question by introducing, excerpting from, and then linking to *any* online resource - whether that's an answer elsewhere on the site, on another SE site, on a vendor's documentation page, or a blog or online book.

Nancy gets reputation if she writes a good answer: relating the link to the question being answered, quoting relevant portions of it, [attributing the original author](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), etc.

The only interesting aspects of this are:

1. We don't have to worry so much about getting a copyright violation complaint from Mary if she feels Nancy has excerpted too much of her answer, at least as long as Nancy attributes it properly.
2. Mary can get reputation and recognition on the site when readers follow the (mandatory) link back to the source, read and vote on her original answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to explain this.